# QGIS display functions seizes to work

Tags: qgis, display

I work as a student GIS analyst in a small company and am at my wits' end.

Several colleagues had a problem where when they opened a QGIS project, all layer styles were displayed in blue, regardless of the initial layer style. When I would open the project, everything would be blue as well. I could change the styles back to the desired color scheme, but when the affected colleagues opened the project, the changes were lost and everything was blue again.

Now a reinstall of QGIS fixes this problem, but I would like to know if anyone knows and can explain to me what exactly is going on, has this happened to anyone else and can it be fixed or avoided?

I also noticed that the Rendering tab in the Options menu was missing for the affected colleagues. So I assume it is a problem with QGIS rendering capabilities, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem of version. If you use 3.28 to do your symbology, and if you open it in 3.16 for exemple, everything will be in blue…
And if you save it, back in 3.28, everything is also blue!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to export the style to a .qlm-file, the styles are not saved anymore in the qgz-file rather than the corresponding shape-file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying vector data or raster data? If it's raster, I would recommend saving the symbology. Layer Properties --> Render type = Singleband pseudocolor --> Edit symbology --> 'Export color map to file'